# WordPress Posts share on facebook

Tags: javascript, wordpress, facebook

How i can share my WordPress blog posts on Facebook. But without using sharing button. there should be custom link below each posts like

```
show this post on Facebook - share
```

when i click on this link post will be share on Facebook accordingly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use direct link

`<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<?php get_the_permalink( get_the_ID() ) ?>" onclick="javascript:window.open(this.href,'', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=600,width=600');return false;">show this post on Facebook - share</a>`